# Cannot find SafeCopy In Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, lubuntu, safecopy

Sorry, I'm very new with this.
I have installed SafeCopy with the following commands, and everything was looking fine.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install safecopy
```

My problem is that I just cannot find the application in Ubuntu. It is not in app list.
Please let me know where can I find it and run it. Thank you.

Megasurf

[image]

Comment: If you want a GUI for backups of files and directories, you could look into [this list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514963/is-there-any-gui-application-for-command-rsync).

Answer (score 0):

safecopy is a command-line application. It does not show in the GUI list of applications. You can execute safecopy by opening a terminal and entering `safecopy`. By default when executed without parameters, it shows the usage instructions.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. What about SafeCopy Control Panel GUI interface? Check the screenshot above. Regards

Comment: There's no GUI for `safecopy`.  The screenshot you shared appears to be for a defunct backup company.